# Parking Mania (Lite) - Impossible Level 15

Tags: parking-mania-lite

I'm stuck on level 15 of [Parking Mania (Lite)](http://itunes.apple.com/app/parking-mania-lite/id329983824?mt=8). Steering the truck around the left-right-right-left bend I always end up waiting at the traffic light with my rear halfway across the street. Some A.I. traffic will arrive from behind and squeeze in next to my trailer, inevitably crashing into it when I try to make the next right turn.

[image: stupid traffic]

Any advice on how to beat this level/work around stupidities in the A.I.?

Comment: same i am always stuck on this level. i can never park into the space. i can manage to get round the curves. ps: there is a secret road just at the top of where you need to collect the wood.

Comment: omg im stuck on this one to i cant get into the parking space its so annoyingggggg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually succeeded by lurking in the left lane (fortunately no oncoming traffic in this level) until there was a large enough gap in the traffic to slip around the corner. Very inelegant, but a solution for this annoying bug.

Answer (score 0):

Go on the outside lane and go when the traffic light is red so you do not hit any traffic. I have not completed this level yet but this seemed to have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a wide turn, go on the left lane and turn.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for all of that. After taking the trailer take a complete U turn. You will find a small gap, through which you should go. Once you go in it, you will reach an intersection. When you get there, take a left. This will leave you in a small path and then you'll be able to cross that junction.